# Why do my dropdown buttons not work with google maps embedded?

Tags: html, google-maps, drop-down-menu, navbar, bootstrap-4

When I embed my google map, the dropdown menu in the navbar and navbar hamburger become inactive, nothing at all happens when I click on them.

This is my page with the google map embedded:

```html
<body>
<nav>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <img src="Owlswick Logo.svg" width="300" height="75" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

  <!--dropdown-->
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Owlswick Morris</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="Present Owlswick.html">Present Owlswick</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="Our History.html">Our History</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="Jane Reasons.html">Jane's 5 Reasons to Morris Dance</a>

    </div>
  </li>
  <div>
</nav>

<div id="map">
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJyaAw2pB9d0gRNqb4LwxJCnc&key=AIzaSyDqL1wqNr0OJe9rkXYPirEe8REMDNJM_5E" allowfullscreen</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks as though the `<iframe>` tag is malformed. Did you copy it out wrong on here or is that your actual production code?

Comment: @G.Hunt That is the actual production code. I copy and pasted straight from google maps...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to G.Hunt I solved my problem.

I got another embed code from google maps and now my buttons all work correctly.